# E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed

Tags: 18.04, apt, update-manager

```
root@tet0-Lenovo-G500s:/home/tet0# apt-get update

 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease [55.7 kB]    
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease               

W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Ask an actual question preferably explicitly mentioning your distro with its version and explaining why you have `precise` in the output. Just posting terminal output isn't enough.

Comment: i am getting error: "E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed" while updating  apt package.

Comment: If you are attempting to use 12.04 repositories, then why is 18.04 tagged?

Comment: where did i mentioned 12.04? @user535733

Comment: 'precise' is the codename for Ubuntu 12.04. If you are NOT using 12.04, then delete those lines from your /etc/apt/sources.list. Then run `sudo apt update`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: thank you :) @user535733

Comment: One more point, it appears that you're running as `root`. Unless you're 100% sure of what you're doing, running as `root` is inadvisable. The safer route is to use `sudo` whenever you need elevated privileges.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)